# use IFNULL in DQL and symfony query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

subquery and querybuilder in my project 
but when use ```IFNULL`` command in query return eroor
my code is bellow

```
  $subQb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $subquery = $subQb->select('COUNT(v.id)')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Visitsite', 'v')
                ->where('v.site = s.id')
                ->Andwhere('v.createdate > :date')
                ->getDQL();

            $subQb2 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $subquery2 = $subQb2->select('l.quantity')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Limitviewday', 'l')
                ->where($subQb2->expr()->eq('s.limitviewday', 'l.id'))
                ->getDQL();


            $subQb3 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $subquery3 = $subQb3->select('COUNT(i.id)')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Visitsite', 'i')
                ->where('i.id = s.id')
                ->Andwhere('i.createdate > :date2')
                ->Andwhere('i.ip = :ip')
                ->groupBy('i.ip')
                ->getDQL();

            $subQb4 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $subquery4 = $subQb4->select('ipl.quantity')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Iplimitview', 'ipl')
                ->where('s.iplimitview = ipl.id')
                ->getDQL();


            $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $query = $qb->select('s')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Sites', 's')
                ->where('s.quantity > :one')
                ->Andwhere('s.status = :two')
                ->Andwhere($qb->expr()->lt("($subquery)", "($subquery2)"))
                ->Andwhere($qb->expr()->lt("(SELECT IFNULL(  ($subquery3),0) )", "($subquery4))"))
                ->setParameter('one', 1)
                ->setParameter('two', 1)
                ->setParameter('date', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
                ->setParameter('ip', $ip)
                ->setParameter('date2', $date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'));
```

and my result is

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 274: Error: Expected known function, got
>   'IFNULL'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine has limited set of mapped functions, and seems it has no IFNULL by default.

The simple way is to change your DQL and replace IFNULL with IF or COALESCE.

The more difficult way is read [manual](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) and implement your own IFNULL mapping [like this](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/src/Query/Mysql/IfNull.php)